# How can I insert new food data to specific category id

Tags: flutter, dart

```
final List <Category> _categories = [
    Category(
        id: '1',
        title: 'Poultry',
        food: [
            Food(
                id: '1',
                title: 'Chicken 1',
                description: "qdwwqd",
                price: 500.00,
                image: "https://jb-ph-cdn.tillster.com/menu-images/prod/45df1872-c7f7-4b3d-baa9-1b0c4f56a5cc.png",
                choice: [],
            ),
        ],
    ),
    Category(
        id: '2',
        title: 'Vegetables',
        food: [
            Food(
                id: '1',
                title: 'Cabbage',
                description: "qdwwqd",
                price: 500.00,
                image: "https://jb-ph-cdn.tillster.com/menu-images/prod/45df1872-c7f7-4b3d-baa9-1b0c4f56a5cc.png",
                choice: [],
            ),
        ],
    ),
]
'''
```

Comment: Please when posting code, surround the code with three backticks (`) to let SO know its supposed to be rendered as code

Comment: Or indent the whole block of code by 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert new data into the food array, first you need to find the correct category:

```
String myID = '1';
int index = _categories.indexWhere((cat) => cat.id == myID);
```

Once you did that, it is quite simple:

```
_categories[index].food.add(Food());
```